# The code meant to generate [((0,0),0), ((0,1),0), ((1,0),0), ((1,1),0)] actually gives [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], how to fix it?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate a set of all possible combinations of {0,1} and {00,01,10,11}, which is supposed to be an array that has the shape of (16,4)

things like

```
[[((0,0),0), ((0,1),0), ((1,0),0), ((1,1),0)],
[((0,0),0), ((0,1),0), ((1,0),0), ((1,1),1)],
...
[((0,0),1), ((0,1),1), ((1,0),1), ((1,1),1)],
...
]]
```

This needs not actually be array, I misused the term array since list has no shape :)

'00' is good, (0, 0) is better, since the latter has a good looking,

**Note:** there is supposed to be 16 items in the outer list and 4 items in the inner list

the code could give the smallest block

```
bset = np.array([0,1])
fset = np.array(np.meshgrid(bset,bset)).T.reshape(-1,2)
[tuple(i) for i in fset]
```

which is

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

so far, so cool, and then things get messed.

this code

```
np.array(np.meshgrid(t4,bset), np.object)
```

gives

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=object)
```

other than something like

```
[((0,0),0), ((0,1),0), ((1,0),0), ((1,1),0)]
```

I also tried itertools

```
arr = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
list(combinations(arr, 2))
```

which is close

```
[((0, 0), (0, 1)),
 ((0, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((0, 0), (1, 1)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 0)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 0), (1, 1))]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure these need to be arrays? `numpy` arrays are not really meant to be used with data types which are not numbers (like tuples). Are you sure you need an array?

Comment: @kabanus This needs not actually be array, I misused the term array since list has no shape :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in the following way:

```
>>> options = (0, 1)
>>> base = list(it.product(options, options))
>>> output = [list(zip(base, i)) for i in it.product(*[options]*4)]
>>> pprint(output)
[[((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 1)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without numpy. Let's say you have two lists like this:

```
>>> l1 = ['0', '1']
>>> l2 = ['00','01','10','11']  # using string as your question is unclear, see below
```

You can use `itertools.product` like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> result = list(itertools.product(l1, l2))
>>> result
[('0', '00'), ('0', '01'), ('0', '10'), ('0', '11'), ('1', '00'), ('1', '01'), ('1', '10'), ('1', '11')]
```

`itertools.product` returns an iterable.

In our question your input set is `{00,01,10,11}` and in output you want `(0, 0),..` is this some typo?

You can perform `itertools.product` on `set` too but the set you provided in your question is not valid python code.

Still your question is unclear about the inputs but I am assuming it's:

```
set1 = {0, 1}
set2 = {(0, 0, ), (0, 1, ), (1, 0, ), (1, 1, )}  # if you have a string or something else, convert it to tuple
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
import pprint
result = [list(itertools.product(set2, [x])) for x in set1]
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[[((0, 1), 0), ((1, 0), 0), ((0, 0), 0), ((1, 1), 0)],
 [((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((0, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 1)]]
```

Comment: '00' is good, (0, 0) is better, since the latter has a good looking, **Note** there is supposed to be 16 items in the outer list and 4 items in the inner list